# Google Analytics implemented at JavaScript not tracking on Android Device

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, google-analytics

I am working on a Hybrid Model Application Development. My base code is in AngularJS and built the app with bootstrap and HTML5 for responsiveness and have Xamrin at the middle layer to provide me with platform dependent bridges for appropriate platforms(Android and iOS).

I have implemented Google Analytics at Javascript level. As we have plans of supporting more platforms in the future, we don't want to implement GA at the native level. Instead, treat the application as webpage and add the tracking at the UI level. This way, regardless of the platform, we will be able to track the analytics.

However, I've implemented this for iOS and Surface.Both of them are tracking analytics perfectly. But not Android.

In my Index.html file, I have this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ga.js"></script>
<script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
 if(GA_Enabled_Flag === true){
 _gaq.push(['_setAccount', GA_Tracking_ID]);
 _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
 }
</script>
```

which is not working only on Android environment.

Any thoughts on this would be greatly helpful.

Thanks,
Madhan

Comment: Any word on this anyone?

Comment: Doesn't work for me also.